# How to log into file using log4js when I get a error response?

Tags: express, log4js-node

I want to log into some file when I only get a error response from client. And I want to print messages on terminal when I get the others. So, I'm using `express` and `log4js` like that.

Here is some part of my code.

```
const log4js = require('log4js'),
  express = require('express'),
  app = express();

log4js.configure({
  appenders: [
    {type: 'console'},
    {type: 'file', filename: 'logs/logs.log', category: 'file'}
  ]
});

const fileLogger = log4js.getLogger('file'),
  consoleLogger = log4js.getLogger('console');

fileLogger.setLevel('ERROR');

app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use(log4js.connectLogger(fileLogger, { format: ':method :url' }));
app.use(log4js.connectLogger(consoleLogger, { level: 'auto', format: ':method :url' }));
```

I expected that error response is filtered by fileLogger then a log message is written into `logs.log` and the others are filtered by consoleLogger then the message is printed on terminal but not.

Is there a good way to solve it using `connectLogger`?

Answer (score 0):

I referred to [this](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node/issues/154) and I knew that It's impossible to use `connectLogger` multiple times for express routing.

Answer (score 0):

Call different category logger in order to show log to different action.

```
var logger = log4js.getLogger('file');
```

User connectLogger only once in app.js!